# Count lines fast

Tags: windows-7, speed, gnuwin32, unix-utils

I'm running Windows 7 and have GnuWin32. I have a several-gigabyte text file with LF (`\n`) line endings. I want to know how many lines it has (or alternatively how many LFs it has, which is, let's say, one fewer, but I don't care). What's the fastest or least expensive way to get my answer?

Some possibilities (though I'm sure I'm missing some):

- `wc -l foo`
- `grep -c $ foo` (with `-c`, prints only the count of matching lines)
- `grep -c ^^ foo` (the first caret escapes the second)
- `sed -n $= foo` (`-n` prevents printing the line; `$` restricts to the last line; `=` prints the line number)

(Those are the GnuWin32 utilities. I don't know of any native-to-Windows way.)

Comment: My answer gives a number of other possibilities. I will let you do the timings and let us all know which is the fastest ;)

Comment: Did you come to any conclusions?

Answer (score 4):

#### Windows command line solution

```
type foo | find "" /v /c
```

---

#### Powershell solutions

```
(get-content foo | measure-object -line).lines

(dir foo | select-string .).count

(type foo).count

(gc foo | measure-object | select count).count
```

---

#### perl solution

```
perl -pe '}{$_=$.' foo
```

---

#### awk solution

```
awk 'END { print NR }' foo
```

---

#### Further reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [find](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) - Search for a text string in a file & display all the lines where it is found.
- [An A-Z Index of Windows PowerShell commands](http://ss64.com/ps/) - An excellent reference for all things PowerShell related.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest for me is the command line: `find /v /c "" foo.txt`

I am yet to do a proper benchmark but I tried `type` and `(get-content foo | measure-object -line)` for a 10GB file on a 2GB ram server, but they took far too long to complete. Find however returned fast enough

Comment: You propose a solution which is already suggested. Please pay an answer only if it provides additional information. Have you compared multiple ways? Which ones? What was the result? What was your test case?  ...

Comment: @MátéJuhász I didn't find it elsewhere, `find` command is not the same as `type`. Posted in a hurry but will update answer with more details.